# Velocity - get the current class name?

Tags: velocity

If the name of the class is ClassName1000, how do I get the name of the class and how do I get only the number in the name of the class.

```
//if code name is ClassName1000, I want to get numbers after ClassName. 
#set($className = ????)
#set($number = $className.split("[Name]")[1]);

// if I call $number, I want to get 1000
```

What should I do? I need some help!

Comment: Could you more specificly state whether you don't know how to get the current class name from within velocity or if you have problems with separating the number from this class name? There seems to be some confusion as to how to interpret this question.

Comment: I solved what I wanted to know 


`#set($className = ${NAME})`

`#if($className.contains("ClassName"))`
    `#set($classNum  = $className.split("ClassName"))`
    `${classNum.get(1)}`

Comment: Doesn't this already answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

I have not get any better way So the simple way it should be `replaceAll`

```
#set($number = $str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));

The value of class: $number
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how to get the name of the class

Comment: @RikSchaaf did you read the question fully dont just blindly downvote?

Comment: I downvoted it because it only answers the second part of the question, while neglecting to explain how to get the class name in the first place (as the title suggests that Dave wants to know). I might have been too quick on the downvote though, as you did in fact answer part of the question. If you edit your post to answer the other subquestion as well, I  will change my vote to an upvote.

Comment: i don't need your vote I'm happy  that you understood. OP clearly mentioned `if I call $number, I want to get 1000` . He is trying to get number.

Comment: While he is indeed trying to separate the number from the class name, he more or less states that he wants this number from the current class and I interpret that as him not knowing how to access this name from velocity.